# Strongswan running in container to create VPN tunnel between LAN and GCE?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, strongswan

I've got a CentOS 7 VM running [strongSwan](https://www.strongswan.org/) which sets up a VPN tunnel between our LAN and Google Compute Engine ([Google Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/overview)). This makes local machines on the LAN accessible by GCE instances and vice versa.

I'd like to run strongSwan in a Docker container instead of the resource hungry VM. However, I'm pretty sure I cannot make the container aware of our LAN and therefore not make GCE instances access the machines on our LAN (and vice versa) - as the VPN tunnel would only be created between the container's network and Google's network.

Am I correct or can this somehow be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

strongSwan uses IPsec in tunnel mode, which (on Linux) requires loading and using a few [kernel modules](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/KernelModules). Loading the module and configuring it is not something you can do inside a normal container. You can get around this by making the container privileged and using a "host" mode network so that the container can see the tunnel it creates(`docker run --privileged --net=host`), but essentially this disables the isolation between the container and it's host, so it's probably not what you want.